# Jenkins changing the email password that I saved

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I am attempting to test, and use, the [Email-ext plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), and have set it up according to documentation, including setting the SMTP server to `smtp.gmail.com:465`, entering a default email suffix, entering my username,password into the SMTP authentication fields, clicked "Use SSL", ...
I applied changes and saved afterwards, and then come back, and see that Jenkins has hashed my saved password in the password field, as that 8 to 16 character password of mine is not there.

[image]

How do I fix this, so that I can get on with fulfilling our business requirements?

**UPDATE**: I tried these same steps (setting up the email,password,...) with the much simpler email service that email-ext is designed to replace, and get exception instantly; /* here are the results */

[image: I went to test the email configuration by sending test email and was greeted with this exception stack trace...]

Comment: /* This is issue, as Jenkins seems to be attempting to login to my account with that hashed password, instead of the plaintext one that I entered */

Comment: I doubt it's using the password hash to authenticate. I used the email-ext plugin successfully for years. I would check the logs for a specific error message and confirm that you have the correct credentials. The hash is displayed in the UI for security purposes only.

Comment: @DanWilson I'm about to edit this question to show the exception stack trace....

Comment: Did you provide a _Test e-mail recipient_? The textbox is blank, and the exception says that an empty string is an invalid address.

Comment: I tried again....

Comment: @DanWilson I updated the screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried port 587 (or not specifying a port) instead?

Comment: I try port 587 (the TLS port) and get this exception stack trace : https://imgur.com/a/59CIvNd
Specifying no port at all gives me an HTTP 403 error.

Comment: @DanWilson do you mind actually helping me out here?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, and I don't have an instance for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be not the password being saved encrypted, but rather I was using my personal account, which, in accordance to my employer's rules, has two-factor authentication enabled. I got a generic no-reply account from my boss, waited a half hour, used it, and all was good.